# Find (by name) and delete a directory and its contents

Tags: ssh, find, delete-file

I have been able to create the following command, which works to an extent:

`find . -type d -name "thumbs" -delete`

However, it only deleted the empty folders. If it found a folder called 'thumbs' that wasn't empty, it didn't delete it.

How can I find all folders called 'thumbs' and delete them, including their contents?

Comment: Found the answer! Use the following (with caution):

`find . -type d -name "thumbs" -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: You should post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I would have at the time if it were not for the silly time restrictions placed on new users answering their own questions. I've posted, but still can't accept it until tomorrow! I'm not coming back again...

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer! Use the following (with caution):

`find . -type d -name "thumbs" -exec rm -rf {} \;`